# Prove that $1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{2^n} \ge 1+\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, harmonic-numbers

Is it true that $1+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+ \dots +\dfrac{1}{2^n} \geq 1+\dfrac{n}{2}$?

If so, a proof would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: How can $\frac{1}{3}$ be a term in the sequence when the $n$th term is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The sequence ends at 1/8 or 1/64, etc....

Comment: Maybe I've confused $n$th term with general term.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did a double take and how he presented the series, but then I realized what he meant.

Comment: Have you got the right series?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\ge \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\ge \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$$
$$\geq 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: Looks like Nicole's Oresme proof.